# Unable to install ubuntu13.10-desktop-amd64

Tags: system-installation

Am using acer aspire E1-522 with windows 8.1 pro. I made a bootable USB using winMd5Sum and then i reboot my system and select USB as primary boot device and save it. After that when Ubuntu menu opens i select Install Ubuntu, then I get error

```
*(intitramfs) calling: test builtin

error reading /lib/udev/hwdb.bin: No such file or directory

load module index

unload module index

calling: test -builtin

error reading /lib/udev/hwdb.bin: No such file or directory

load module index

unload module index

mount: mounting /dev/loop0 (cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs)on filesystem.squashfs*
```

please help, am not at all technically sound.

Comment: Try Ubuntu Live with your USB pendrive. If you can boot into the live session then all is ok and you can try to install Ubuntu using the Live Installer icon from the desktop. Choose **Something else** when you get to the screen with the options for installing Ubuntu. This way you can decide which partition you want to allocate for Ubuntu, and also  format the partition to Linux ext4 and make another small partition (2GB max) for Linux swap.

Comment: i have tried all the options but i always get the same error.

Comment: [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) is the tool for writing Ubuntu iso image on the pendrive. You download your flavour of Ubuntu as iso image, and load it in Unetbootin using the **DiskImage** field. Next check your USB drive letter at the bottom of the window, and press OK to write the image. You should format your pendrive to FAT32 first of all. And if nothing works, then you should definitely try to burn the iso image on a DVD, and boot into the live session with the DVD. You can choose to install Ubuntu while in the live session using the Live Installer icon from the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I think USB device has missing files as you see.

Create a new bootable USB with [Lili USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Format your USB drive and use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) or [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to copy Ubuntu ISO image contents to USB drive.

Comment: i hv used unetbootin but its showing same error